# Javascript Callback timeout

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QRtLy/)

Can someone help me understand why the first `setTimeout` works but not on `second` one? Please see comments on the code.

In this case, I want to alert first `I am first` then after 6 seconds, it would alert `Hello, sorry I am late`

```
function iAmTakingTooLong(message1, message2, callback){       
    //setTimeout(function(){ alert('test'); },6000); //THIS WILL WAIT FOR 6000 MILLISECONDS
    setTimeout(callback(message1+message2),6000);    //THIS WILL NOT WAIT FOR 6000 MILLISECONDS
}


iAmTakingTooLong('Hello, ', 'sorry I am late!', function(fullmessage){
    alert(fullmessage);
});

alert("I am first!");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this code:

```
setTimeout(callback(message1+message2),6000);
```

you're **calling** the callback function right there in the argument list. JavaScript evaluates function arguments before calling the function, so what actually gets passed to `setTimeout()` here is whatever the callback function returns.

You need something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { callback(message1 + message2); }, 6000);
```

The behavior here is not unique to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks man, I am just wondering since I was thinking that the callback is already a function and doesn't need to put it inside `function(){}`

Comment: What would you expect `callback(message1 + message2)` to do *outside* of a call to `setTimeout()`?

Comment: I am expecting that without putting `callback(message1+message2)` inside `function(){}`, it would call the callback only after the specified time. But it seems that is not the case. Thank you.